# Why does the time to hash increase in the node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this piece of code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function doHash() {
    const start = Date.now();
    crypto.pbkdf2('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {//some crypto task done by os
        console.log('time required to hash', Date.now() - start)
    })
}
```

If I run it only once:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    doHash();
}
```

The time of 1st hash is **523**

When I run it 4 times

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    doHash();
}
```

The time of 1st hash is increased to **691**

```
time required to hash 691
time required to hash 711
time required to hash 812
time required to hash 847
```

If I run the code 8 times:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    doHash();
}
```

The time of 1st hash is increased to **682** and it's more than doubling for the 8th hash

```
time required to hash 682
time required to hash 712
time required to hash 822
time required to hash 830
time required to hash 1528
time required to hash 1532
time required to hash 1570
time required to hash 1621
```

Why is the time to hash is increasing like this? What is this concept behind this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

because `start` doesn't change and meanwhile you are producing a new date every loop that's why the difference is only getting a bigger, `date.now()` produces a larger date every time.
if you want to solve this add `start` inside the function

```
function doHash() {
const start = Date.now();
    crypto.pbkdf2('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {//some crypto task done by os
        console.log('time required to hash', Date.now() - start)
    })
}
```

a clarification why my above solution didn't work
if you tried to `console.log(start)`

you will see that start variable is still nearly the same and will get logged 8 times and then this will be logged

```
time required to hash 682
time required to hash 712
time required to hash 822
time required to hash 830
time required to hash 1528
time required to hash 1532
time required to hash 1570
time required to hash 1621
```

the function gets called 8 times in the `event loop` hence the right time is not calculated, the solution for this is to turn your `doHash` function into `Async`
and make `await` for it before calling it next time

Comment: @MohammedZameer What? The problem is not related to the hash function.

Comment: i will edit my answer to till you why it doesn't work

Comment: The right time is calculated. This is not the answer

Answer (score 0):

The catch is that while Node.js is single-threaded, some libraries are multi-threaded.

See articles:

- [Is Node.js Really Single-Threaded?](https://medium.com/better-programming/is-node-js-really-single-threaded-7ea59bcc8d64)
- [Node.Js Under the Hood](https://medium.com/better-programming/learn-node-js-under-the-hood-37966a20e127)

Let's modify your code a bit:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function doHash(i) {
    const start = Date.now();
    console.log(`Started task ${i} at ${start}`);
    crypto.pbkdf2('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {
        console.log('time required to hash', Date.now() - start)
    })
}

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    doHash(i);
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
Started task 0 at 1595017877134
Started task 1 at 1595017877140
Started task 2 at 1595017877140
Started task 3 at 1595017877140
Started task 4 at 1595017877140
Started task 5 at 1595017877140
Started task 6 at 1595017877140
Started task 7 at 1595017877140
time required to hash 568
time required to hash 563
time required to hash 564
time required to hash 569
time required to hash 1138
time required to hash 1140
time required to hash 1142
time required to hash 1146
```

You see that:

- all tasks are scheduled at (roughly) the same moment
- tasks seem to finish their work in groups of 4

The reason for this behaviour:

> Node.js internally uses the libuv library which is responsible for handling operating system related tasks, like asynchronous I/O based operation systems, networking, concurrency, etc.
>
> Libuv sets up a thread pool of four threads to perform OS-related operations by utilizing the power of all the CPU cores. Given our machine has four cores, each thread from the pool is assigned to every core.
>
> This results in one thread per core. With this setup, all the four threads will execute logHashTime() in each core in parallel, which makes all the four functions take a similar amount of time.

When you schedule more than 4 tasks, they need to wait for an available worker.

The tasks are picked up by workers independently, but given that the tasks are the same size (same function is executed), you observe grouping by 4.